# Hi, my links don't work. Every time I try to click on them it prompts an error except for the homepage (index) link

Tags: html, css

I've tried to edit the CSS without results. I've checked the positions of the folders and everything is OK (big folder project with other folders inside (homepage, products...). Everyone of them has their own CSS that resembles the one you see here.
One more detail: links worked yesterday so the error must be inside CSS! But at the same time the index link works, while the others don't, so this just makes no sense to me.

THIS IS HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="menu-bar">
        <ul id="menu">
                <div class="col-3">
                  <li>
                  <a href="index.html" target="_blank"> <img src="img/apewhite.png" width="200%" height="200%"> </a>
                  </li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 home">
                  <li>
                  <a class= "menu" href="index.html"target="_blank"> Home 
                  </a>
                  </li> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 abt">
                  <li>
                  <a class= "menu" href="../AboutUs/AboutUs.html"target="_blank"> About us 
                  </a>
                  </li> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 prd">
                  <li>
                  <a class= "menu" href="../products/products.html"target="_blank"> Products 
                  </a>
                  </li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 research">
                  <li>
                  <a class= "menu" href="../R&D/R&D.html"target="_blank"> Research&Development
                  </a>
                  </li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 news">
                  <li>
                  <a class= "menu" href="../News_Events/News_&_Events.html" target="_blank"> News&Events 
                  </a>
                  </li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 contacts">
                  <li>
                  <a class= "menu" href="../Contacts/contacts.html"target="_blank"> Contacts 
                  </a>
                  </li> 
                </div>
          </ul>
         
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
/*THIS IS CSS*/

body {
 background-image: url(../img/nanotech.jpg);
  background-size: 105%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-width: 105%;
 
  }

.container-fluid
{
width: 105%;
overflow: hidden;
}
.home, .abt, .prd, .research, .news, .contacts {
  margin-top: 12px;

}

.home {
margin-left:1.5%;
  margin-right: 3%;

}

.abt {
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.prd {
margin-right: 4.5%;

}

.research {
  margin-right: 5%;

}  

.news {
  
  margin-right: -1.5%;


}
.contacts {


}

.menu-bar{
opacity: 0.9;
width: 105%;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #B22222;

}

#menu {
 position:relative; /* <- thing I've tried to add */
    z-index:1; /* <- thing I've tried to add */
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 6px;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left:0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 60px;
}

#menu li {

 position:relative; /* <- thing I've tried to add*/
    z-index:1; /* <- thing I've tried to add */
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 2px;
    float: left;/* <- I've tried to get rid of it but the error persists*/
}


ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
display:inline-flex;

}

a
{
padding: 5px;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

a.menu:link {text-decoration: none} 
a.menu:visited {color : white}
a.menu:active {color : white}
a.menu:hover {color: white}

li ul
{
display: none
}

li:hover ul
{
opacity: 90%;
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index:1;
height:110px;
width:220px;
padding: 5px;
margin-top: 3%;
background: #B22222;

}
#sub {
margin-top:1%;

  }


li li { border:none; width:150px; }
li li a { padding:2px 2px 2px 10px; }
```

Comment: HI , welcome to stackoverfow. Could you trim down your code? That way, other users can easier help you identify your problem.

Comment: You probably meant to use `./` instead of `../`

Answer (score 1):

If your index.html is in same directory as other folders then no need to add `..` double dots even `/` slash at start of path.
i am considering you have following directory tree

```
index.html
     |-Aboutus
        |-aboutus.html
     |-products
        |-products.html
```

```css
 
        body {
 background-image: url(../img/nanotech.jpg);
  background-size: 105%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  max-width: 105%;
 
  }

.container-fluid
{
width: 105%;
overflow: hidden;
}
.home, .abt, .prd, .research, .news, .contacts {
  margin-top: 12px;

}

.home {
margin-left:1.5%;
  margin-right: 3%;

}

.abt {
  margin-right: 5%;
}

.prd {
margin-right: 4.5%;

}

.research {
  margin-right: 5%;

}  

.news {
  
  margin-right: -1.5%;


}
.contacts {


}

.menu-bar{
opacity: 0.9;
width: 105%;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #B22222;

}

#menu {
 position:relative; /* <- thing I've tried to add */
    z-index:1; /* <- thing I've tried to add */
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 6px;
margin-right: 0;
margin-left:0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    height: 60px;
}

#menu li {

 position:relative; /* <- thing I've tried to add*/
    z-index:1; /* <- thing I've tried to add */
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 2px;
    float: left;/* <- I've tried to get rid of it but the error persists*/
}


ul
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style-type: none;
display:inline-flex;

}

a
{
padding: 5px;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}

a.menu:link {text-decoration: none} 
a.menu:visited {color : white}
a.menu:active {color : white}
a.menu:hover {color: white}

li ul
{
display: none
}

li:hover ul
{
opacity: 90%;
display: block;
position: absolute;
z-index:1;
height:110px;
width:220px;
padding: 5px;
margin-top: 3%;
background: #B22222;

}
#sub {
margin-top:1%;

  }


li li { border:none; width:150px; }
li li a { padding:2px 2px 2px 10px; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="menu-bar">
            <ul id="menu">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html" target="_blank"> <img src="img/apewhite.png" width="200%" height="200%"> </a>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 home">
                    <li>
                        <a class= "menu" href="index.html"target="_blank"> Home </a>
                    </li> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 abt">
                    <li>
                        <a class= "menu" href="AboutUs/AboutUs.html"target="_blank"> About us </a>
                    </li> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 prd">
                    <li>
                        <a class= "menu" href="products/products.html"target="_blank"> Products </a>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 research">
                    <li>
                        <a class= "menu" href="R&D/R&D.html"target="_blank"> Research&Development</a>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 news">
                    <li>
                        <a class= "menu" href="News_Events/News_&_Events.html" target="_blank"> News&Events </a>
                    </li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 contacts">
                    <li>
                        <a class= "menu" href="Contacts/contacts.html"target="_blank"> Contacts </a>
                    </li> 
                </div>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`../` is for going back a dir (folder) by two steps.
If you are trying to reach a file called `products.html` in a `products` dir, you need to simply write `products/products.html`.

Note that if this navigation pane is to appear on other pages inside different "directories" (folders), it is best to use the full path of the file's location.

Another thing that is recommended is to always to use lower cases (small letters), so your users won't get errors trying to reach your site.

Hope this helps, and welcome to StackOverflow!